# Error in workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow, 2016

The Filter workflow worked fine, but at one point it failed:

> the item in the workflow could not be Updated, perhaps because one or
>   more columns for this item must contain data of a different type.

When you try to overwrite a workflow through SharePoint Designer when you publish, you receive an error:

> (370, 15) the Field cannot be of type void)

Comment: which workflow actions you are using exactly? and what is the type of column? is it required?

Comment: Can be more detail, so as not quite understood?

Comment: Really need help

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do in your workflow? if you can ad Screenshot or steps of workflow that will be helpful for us to answer your question.

Comment: There is a time Off list, the workflow must approve the time off and sort by category.

Comment: Even throws this error when creating a clean process for a list